# Webpage reloading only when internet is available

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following piece of code from my webpage that checks for Internet connectivity.

When Internet is available, it should reload the page after 10 seconds. Otherwise, it waits indefinitely for connectivity.

```
function checkJSNetConnection(){
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var file = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9d7ri25ku7xlj9u/WALL-E%20%281%29.jpg?dl=0";
 var r = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);

 xhr.open('HEAD', file + "?subins=" + r, false);

 try {
  xhr.send();

  if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304) {
   return  true;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 } catch (e) {
  return false;
 }
}

function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
  if(checkJSNetConnection()==false){
    alert("Internet Connection does not Exist");
  } else {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
  }
}
```

The function is called from:

```
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(10000);">
```

The problem is that, although it successfully reloads the page when Internet is available, it doesn't show an alert message for no connectivity, showing instead "unable to load page".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about it, if there is an internet connection, it sets the page to reload after 10 seconds right?

so, lets assume it passed the internet connectivity test, and 10 seconds countdown started. now suddenly connection is lost, the countdown reaches zero and refreshes the page (tries to get a new copy of it from the website) but since there is no internet connectivity, it just fails and says that the page is not available.

**a possible solution:** (there are more, this is one)

dont set a time out, if internet is available, reload right away and start a new timeout on the connectivity check:

change "timed refresh" to "timed check" logic:

```
<body onload="JavaScript:setTimeout(timedCheck,10000);">
```

and the script:

```
function timedCheck(timeoutPeriod) {
  if(checkJSNetConnection()==false){
      alert("Internet Connection doesnot Exist");
 }else{
      location.reload(true);
 }
}
```

this way, when the page first loads, it will start a countdown of 10 seconds at the end of which a test will be made. if there is a connection available, it will reload immediately and a new countdown will start. if there is no connection, it will show  the alert.

Comment: Basically, it's currently confirming internet connection at the beginning of the countdown, not the end as it should.

Comment: the problem is not in the connectivity test, the problem is that there is a flaw in the logic which lets the page reload even if there is no connection available. he should reload right away instead of setting a timeout on the refresh

Comment: @Banana , I want to modify "timecheck" if condition ""alert("Internet Connection doesnot Exist");"" to       ""while (checkJSNetConnection()==false); location.reload(true);"""

it works fine but the problem is that slide show on my screen stops on first image and is not transitioning.

Any suggestion??
thanks

Comment: Why would you want to use a while loop? It will get stuck inside the loop forever and wont proceed to the rest of the code... just use an if statement

Comment: so how to make continuation?

Like if the connection of internet is restored so it should continue refreshing after 10 sec again

@Banana

Comment: In addition to the "connection lost" alert (or instead of it) call the timeout again. `setTimeout(timedCheck,10000);`

Comment: It works very well @Banana

you are genius :)

Thanks :)